# How to access nested values in JSON using X-SuperObject

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-10-seattle, xsuperobject

I want to get all the users from this json.

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "next_max_id": "AQAmA1l9NAQXa",
  "sections": [
    {
      "module": null,
      "show_view_all": null,
      "title": null,
      "users": [
        {
          "pk": 48165888,
          "is_verified": false,
          "profile_pic_url": "http://scontent-sit4-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/17332306_1915592632007479a.jpg",
          "full_name": "Jason Giovany Castro Morales",
          "is_private": false,
          "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false,
          "username": "jasongiovanycastromorales",
          "profile_pic_id": "14699765111792881_48165888"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, my attempt to get all usernames.

```
procedure TForm2.Button6Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  json : ISuperObject;
  node : ISuperObject;
  item : IMember;
begin
  try
    json := TSuperObject.Create(list.Text);

    for item in json['sections.users'].AsArray do
    begin
      node := item.AsObject;
      Memo4.Lines.Add(node.S['username']);
    end;
  finally
  end;
end;
```

2nd attempt.. i get an AV !

```
var
    json         : ISuperObject;
    node         : ISuperObject;
    item, item2         : IMember;
  begin
     json := SO(list.Text);

   for item in json['sections'].AsArray do
    begin
       for item2 in json['users'].AsArray do
        begin
        node := item.AsObject;

        Memo1.Lines.Add(node.S['username']);
       end;
     end;
  end;
```

there are 200 username value in this JSON
I get nothing, sometimes AV when i try to play around withthe json code,  my question is, how to parse this json correctly to get the value `username`? Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is broken and you didn't specify the format of input data, like I don't know, if all objects in `sections` array contains `users` array. Anyway, this example should be working for your snippet.

[SuperObject](https://github.com/hgourvest/superobject)

```
procedure TForm2.Button6Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  json, user, section : ISuperObject;
begin
  json := SO(list.Text);
  for section in json['sections'] do
  begin
    if Assigned(section['users']) then
    begin
      for user in section['users'] do
      begin
        if user.S['username'] <> '' then
          Memo4.Lines.Add(user.S['username']);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

**EDIT :**
In fact, you are not using `SuperObject`, but `X-SuperObject`, which is something different. Even though I've never used that library, I was able to find the problem only with examples from their website, because u make simple mistakes like using `item` instead of `item2` or `json` and `item` in second loop.

[X-SuperObject](https://github.com/onryldz/x-superobject)

```
procedure TForm2.Button6Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  json : ISuperObject;
  item, item2 : IMember;
begin
  json := TSuperObject.Create(list.Text);
  for item in json['sections'].AsArray do
  begin
    for item2 in item.AsObject['users'].AsArray do
      Memo1.Lines.Add(item2.AsObject['username'].ToString);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Error `or-in statement cannot operate on collection type 'ISuperExpression' because 'ISuperExpression' does not contain a member for 'GetEnumerator', or it is inaccessible`

Comment: Edited my answer. You should really pay more attention to variables that you use and clearly specify the question.

Comment: My Bad, i thought X-SuperObject is just an upgrade to SuperObject, Many Thanks bro

Answer (score 1):

**DISCLAIMER:** this answer relates to [SuperObject](https://github.com/hgourvest/superobject). At the time, this answer was given, it was unknown that the question actually refers to [XSuperObject](https://github.com/onryldz/x-superobject).

---

> I get nothing

This is unlikely because you should at least get an access violation. This is because, you are not creating the superobject the right way.

I recommend you to use the factory function `SO()` instead of calling the constructor `TSuperObject.Create`.

Then you have to remember that both `sections` and `users` are arrays. Thus, you need to iterate both arrays in a nested iteration:

```
var
  json: ISuperObject;
  section: ISuperObject;
  user: ISuperObject;
begin
  json := SO(list.Text);
  for section in json['sections'] do // iterate sections
    for user in section['users'] do  // iterate users
      Memo4.Lines.Add(user.S['username']);
 end;
```

**Note:** This example is a minimal approach. You should add further checking (e.g. `Assigned()`) to prevent exceptions.

Comment: `for-in statement cannot operate on collection type 'ISuperExpression' because 'ISuperExpression' does not contain a member for 'GetEnumerator', or it is inaccessible` , Thats why i used `IMember`

Comment: I wouldn't have posted my answer without having it compiled and tested before. I got no such error. Where does `ISuperExpression` come from? My code is exclusively iterating over `ISuperObject`'s enumerator, which returns `ISuperObject`s.

Comment: Exactly at this line `for section in json['sections'] do // iterate sections`

Comment: Which version of *SuperObject* do you use? When I look at `ISuperObject`'s declaration, there is `property O[const path: SOString]: ISuperObject read GetO write PutO; default;`. Thus, the return value of `json['sections']` is of type `ISuperObject`, too. The `for..in`-loop requires an enumerator, which is returned from `ISuperObject` by its method `function GetEnumerator: TSuperEnumerator;`. Looking at `TSuperEnumerator`'s declaration, there is - again - only `ISuperObject` returned (`property Current: ISuperObject`). See: https://github.com/hgourvest/superobject/blob/master/superobject.pas